# Select checkbox on website using VBA

Tags: html, vba, checkbox

I have an piece of VBA-code, to log in to a website.

This was quite easy, looking for the ID of the element, and use the code:

```
IE.document.getElementById("Postponement").Click
```

But now I get a problem, because the HTML code of a particular checkbox is only:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectAll, click: actionAllSelected"></input>
```

This is a checkbox to select all customers on this particular page. I want to select them all. Because there is no ID or NAME, I can not use `getElementById`.

Here is the [checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVXsf.jpg), and the HTML code. If you want more information then let me know!

Anyone have an idea to select this checkbox with VBA?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the checkbox please? and the surrounding HTML

Comment: Yes, eee attachement in the question,

Answer (score 0):

try IE.document.getElementsByAttribute("Type")(0).checked="1"